# Как разработать систему инкрементного резервного копирования под windows самостоятельно?

Tags: windows, резервное-копирование, iso-образ

Стоит задача разработать систему инкрементного резервного копирования под windows. Каким образом это сделать? Что использовать? С чего начать?

Comment: [Резервное копирование и восстановление в Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/17143)

Comment: Непонятно. Вы хотите её написать с нуля сами или использовать готовый софт?